# Rings whose every $R$-module $M$ has $\text{End}_R(M)\cong R$ or $\text{End}_R(M)=R$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $_RM$ be a left $R$-module with $S=\text{End}_R(M)$, the ring of endomorphisms of the left $R$-module $M$ and $1$ be the identity endomorphism of $_RM$. It is well known that if $M=R$, then $R\cong S$.   My questions are:

(1) Apart from the module $M=R$, which  other types or classes of modules for which $S\cong R$ or $S=R$?

(2) For which classes of rings or types of ring for which every $R$-modules has $S\cong R$ or $S=R$?

(3) For which rings or modules every $\alpha\in S$ is only right multiplication, that is, $\alpha:M\to M$ is just $m\mapsto ma$ for some $a\in R$?

Comment: $\mathrm{End}(R_R)\cong R$, but $\mathrm{End}(_RR)\cong R^{op}$ (the opposite ring). You'll have to switch sides, or else elaborate the question using $R^{op}$ as well.

Comment: But otherwise, this is pretty interesting.

Comment: For question $(1)$, we can already mention invertible modules. For question $(2)$, this requires at least $M_n(R)\simeq R$ for all $n$, which is pretty strong.

Comment: Consider $M=0$.